# My CNN model accuracy is not improving with ResNet50

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a machine learning project with TensorFlow for sign language recognition.
When I first tried to build my CNN model it has a validation accuracy of 94% :

```
def create_model():  
 model = Sequential(name='SIGNS_LANGUAGE')
 model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE , 3) ) )
 model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
 model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu' ,input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE , 3) ) )
 model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
 #classification layers 
 model.add(layers.Flatten())
 model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(layers.Dense(targetCount, activation='softmax'))
 print(model.summary())
 return model`
```

BUT IT HASN'T BEEN GOOD AT **generalizing** with a different data.

So I tried to work with a pre-trained model like ResNet50 but I couldn't figure out why the accuracy is not improving with time, it hit 40% and stopped:

```
def create_model():
  model = Sequential(name='SIGNS')
  input_shape = (IMG_SIZE , IMG_SIZE , 3)
  res_layer = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False , weights='imagenet' )
  res_layer.trainable = False
  model.add( res_layer )
  model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(layers.Dense(targetCount, activation='softmax'))
  print(model.summary())
  return model
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the model??

N.B: I input 54049 grayscale images in the 3 channels and I use Adam optimizer.

Comment: I have faced the same issue (with another type of pre-trained model) while training models for emotion recognition. If accuracy doesn't improve it means that the model you are using is not suitable for your use case or the data set you use. Try a different model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pre-trained architecture, you have to normalize your data according to the dataset on which the pre-trained architecture was originally trained on(in this case, Imagenet).

Try incorporating this code after your first one -

```
preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(x, data_format=None)
inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = preprocessing_layer(inputs)
outputs = model(x)
inference_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```